# Is there any way to fix the x-axis of a tfvis plot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow.js

The default setting for tfvis seems to be to dynamically update the axes as the epochs progress, but it makes the plot jump around a lot.

I have tried:

```
xAxisDomain: [1,100],
```

in various combinations but these didn't make any difference at all.

One issue could be that I'm *sometimes* getting these two rather nebulous errors. They don't halt the program but could they be relevant?

> (node:15543) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError:
>   document is not defined
>
> (node:15543) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
>   Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing
>   inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a
>   promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node
>   process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag
>   `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
>   https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
>   (rejection id: 9)

Comment: Try the zoomToFit property to "set the chart bounds to just fit the data. This may modify the axis scales but allows fitting more data into view." (from the official documentation)

Comment: This only zooms into the data even more unfortunately. Thanks anyway.